# sidewaystable and APSR

Tags: sidewaystable

I have the following code:

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Please note that whilst this template provides a 
% preview of the typeset manuscript for submission, it 
% will not necessarily be the final publication layout.
%
%% Document class options: (**...** are defaults)
%  - bibtex: Uses bibtex+natbib, chicago.bst 
%  - biblatex: Uses biblatex-chicago
%      You MUST select one of the above two options, depending
%      on whether you prefer bibtex or biblatex. This template
%      contains code that uses bibtex.
%  - twocolumn: Switch to two column for main text
%  - singlespace/onehalfspace/**doublespace**: 
%         changes line spacing for main text
%  - **blind**/nonblind: Anonymises authors 
%         and affiliations, or not
%  - autowc: Automatically inserts a word count
%         after the abstract, using texcount. 
%         The abstract is ignored. 
%         NOTE THAT THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF YOU HAVE  
%         INSTALLED TEXCOUNT, AND HAVE ENABLED --shell-escape
%         OR --enable-write18. (These will work on Overleaf.)
%         If you get an error about "texcount not found", delete
%         the autowc option, and manually specify the wordcount 
%         with \totalwordcount{xxx}.
%%% autowc may cause longer compilation time. You can 
%%% disable it first while actively editing, and only
%%% enable it when you're ready to take stock and check
%%% on your work.
\documentclass[biblatex]{apsr_submission}

\title{American Political Science Review \emph{(APSR)} Submission Template}
 \author{Author One}
       {Affiliation A}
       {Author One is PhD Candidate, ABC Department, Affiliation A, 12345 NY. (a.1@example.edu)}

\author{Author Two}
       {Affiliation C}
       {Author Two is Assistant Professor, Faculty of Z, Affiliation B, 42813. Corresponding Author (a.2@acme.edu) Additional notes about Author Two.}

\author{Author Three}
       {Affiliation B}
       {Author Three is ...}

 %% These are used for the headers
\runningtitle{APSR Submission Template}
\runningauthor{Author One, Author Two, and Author Three} % 4 + Authors, Author One et al. 

%% Useful packages


%% If you are using a custom figure or table environment from a package and it's not getting framed, add \makeframedenv{MyFigure} in the preamble, where the custom figure environment is \begin{MyFigure}...\end{MyFigure}.
%% Currently table, table*, figure, figure*, longtable, supertabular, sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure will be automatically framed.

%% Handy for setting wide tables/figures in landscape
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating} 

\begin{document}

%%% DO NOT REMOVE THESE LINES. For automatic word count.
%TC:ignore
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
Your abstract. It should be at least three lines long to accommodate the dropped-cap. \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
%%% DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. For automatic word count.
%TC:endignore


\section{Introduction}   

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{An example table}
\label{tab:widgets}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Item & Quantity \\\midrule
Widgets & 42 \\
Gadgets & 13
\end{tabular}
\floatnote{This is a note for this table.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

The apsr_submission cls can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o62vz46ucbkc05/apsr_submission.cls?dl=0)

Apparently, the sidewaystable does not work. I got the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.312 \caption
              {The logit model \label{logit}}
?
```

The file apsr class should work with sideways as well.

I cannot figure out where the mistake is. Any help? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The class is faulty. It puts an mdframed environment around the sidewaystable. That doesn't work. Make a bug report.

Comment: Yes indeed. It put a midframed environment around the sideways. The template file indicates: %% If you are using a custom figure or table environment from a package and it's not getting framed, add \makeframedenv{MyFigure} in the preamble, where the custom figure environment is \begin{MyFigure}...\end{MyFigure}.
%% Currently table, table*, figure, figure*, longtable, supertabular, sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure will be automatically framed. I tried to follow this but it does not work. As you said, it is better to make a bug report. Thanks again.

Comment: I know what they did. I checked the code. But it doesn't work, you can't put frames like this around sidewaysfigures. So complain to the authors.

Comment: Indeed, I am writing to the editorial office. Thanks.

Comment: Something really unusual….In the meantime I get an answer from the editorial office, in the cls file I removed the three lines referring to the sidewaystable environment. Surprisingly, I got the table in landscape...and it was framed! I do not know why. I will be waiting for the reply from the author of the class file.

Comment: I got an answer from the editorial office. I am copying the solution here just in case someone needs it. 1. In apsr_submission.cls, comment out lines 262–265.
2. Then in your .tex file, add the mdframed environment manually inside sidewaystable:

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\caption
\floatnote{...}
\end{mdframed}
\end{sidewaystable}

Comment: Better provide an answer instead of putting the solution in the comments.